# GSON deserialization : how to know the objects?

Tags: java, gwt, gson

I try to use gson library to deserialize a flow of objects sent to me.
In all examples i've seen, when the method fromJson is called, we already know what type of object we expect to have.

In my case, I receive a flow of different objects and i'd like to know the best way to know the classes of objects before deserialize them.

```
{ A : {...}, B : { B1 : {...}, B2 : {...} }, C : {...} }
```

In this example, I'd like to have a way to know that 3 objects have been sent to me : A.class, B.class and C.class

Thanks

Answer (score 6, accepted):

[The documentation](https://sites.google.com/site/gson/gson-user-guide#TOC-Serializing-and-Deserializing-Collection-with-Objects-of-Arbitrary-Types) contains examples of deserializations using arbitrary classes or in two passes (first general deserialization in a collection, then content deserialization).

[This exemple](http://code.google.com/p/google-gson/source/browse/trunk/extras/src/main/java/com/google/gson/extras/examples/rawcollections/RawCollectionsExample.java) looks exactly like what you need. You could adapt it to use

```
JsonObject obj = parser.parse(json).getAsJsonObject();
```

to get a `JsonObject` instead of an array so that you can iterate on all properties (using [entrySet](http://google-gson.googlecode.com/svn/trunk/gson/docs/javadocs/index.html)) and deserialize according to the names (`a = gson.fromJson(myjsonelement, A.class);`) by simply mapping names to classes.

Comment: Thank you, JsonArray seems like what I need. I'll try tomorrow. Thanks

Answer (score 3):

If there is a field on the json object that you can use to identify the subclass you need to use, then you can use Gson on Fire: https://github.com/julman99/gson-fire

It has a feature called Type Selector that does exactly what you need.

Imagine a Base class and two child classes, A and B, then the code would look like this:

```
GsonFireBuilder builder = new GsonFireBuilder()
    .registerTypeSelector(Base.class, new TypeSelector<Base>() {
        @Override
        public Class<? extends Base> getClassForElement(JsonElement readElement) {
            String kind = readElement.getAsJsonObject().get("kind").getAsString();
            if(kind.equals("a")){
                return A.class; //This will cause Gson to deserialize the json mapping to A
            } else if(kind.equals("b")) {
                return B.class; //This will cause Gson to deserialize the json mapping to B
            } else {
                return null; //returning null will trigger Gson's default behavior
            }
        }
    });
Gson gson = builder.createGson();
```

Answer (score 2):

Yeah i too stumbled upon this issue. There is no way gson can figure out actual class of a field value. It simply tries to instantiate class used to define the field. Needless to say it is often not what we want.
so if you had, say

```
class C {
    private A a;
    private A c;
}

class B extends A {
}
```

then at runtime you

```
C c;
c.a = new B();
c.c = new B();
```

after deserialisation what you get is

```
c.a.getClass()==A.class;
c.b.getClass()==A.class;
```

so you would have to specify the subclass explicitly. Here is a wrapper class that is gson friendly.

```
public class S<T> {
    private String objectClass; 
    private String rawObjectRepresentation;
    // Gson needs no args constructor
    public S() {
    }

    public S(T obj) {
        objectClass = obj.getClass().getName();
        rawObjectRepresentation = getGson().toJson(obj);
    }

    @SuppressWarnings("unchecked")
    public T extract() throws ClassNotFoundException {
        final Class<?> clazz = Class.forName(objectClass);
        return (T)getGson().fromJson(rawObjectRepresentation, clazz);
    }

    private Gson getGson() {
        return new GsonBuilder().create();
    }

    @Override
    public String toString() {
        return "type:"+objectClass;
    }
}
```