# JSON deserializing List in java with no type information

Tags: java, json, serialization, gson

```
class Result {
  private List orders;// Holds objects of class Object only.
  private Number a;
  private Number b;
}

class Order {
  private Number oid;
  private Number status;
}

public class TestClass {
public static void main(String... args){
    String testString = "{\"orders\":[{\"oid\":\"347\",\"status\":\"1\"},{\"oid\":\"348\",\"status\":\"1\"}],\"a\":14.15,\"b\":0}";
    Gson gson = new GsonBuilder().create(); 
    Result res = gson.fromJson( testString, Result.class );
}
```

Class Result cannot be modified. Json does not have type information of the list and Json is not able to parse.

1. Assuming we cannot change these classes, how will be solve this problem? Consider the case when there can be multiple such lists of different type.
2. What if the list contains objects of multiple types?

Answer (score 1):

When parsing JSon you expect it to have certain structure. For example, you expect that Result objects contain Orders and not strings or whatever. So the parser must be intelligent enough to figure out what kind of objects can be contained in the list. There is no way to know this unless you parametrize your collections. It is believed that all java generics information is erased at compile time. This is not true. Gson for example uses generics to figure out how to parse a specific list value. So if you are using GSon parser and `List<Order>` there is no problem with different list types.

Dealing with different list item classes is another matter. If you can change Json data, for each list item you could encode class name along with its fields. If you absolutely can't change your data classes you would have to revert to interpreting json as collection of hierarchical key-value pairs and do the deserialization yourself.

probably [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11191387/gson-deserialization-how-to-know-the-objects/) thread will be of help